# Tag suggestion for "gerontology" or "anti-aging"

Tags: discussion, tags

According to Wikipedia, [Gerontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerontology) is the study of the social, psychological and biological aspects of aging. It is distinguished from geriatrics, which is the branch of medicine that studies the diseases of older adults.

Gerontology encompasses the following:

- studying physical, mental, and social changes in people as they age
- investigating the aging (ageing) process itself (biogerontology)
- investigating the social and pyschosocial impacts of aging (sociogerontology)
- investigating the psychological effects on aging (psychogerontology)
- investigating the interface of normal aging and age-related disease (geroscience)
- investigating the effects of an ageing population on society
  applying this knowledge to policies and programs, including the macroscopic (for example, government planning) and microscopic (for example, running a nursing home) perspectives.

Also it's good consider to propose anti-aging tag as a separate tag? Or it should be included into gerontology?

Proposed questions to tag with gerontology:

- [Do immortal organisms exist?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/do-immortal-organisms-exist/9168#9168)
- [Do crocodiles age?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/do-crocodiles-age/5208#5208)
- [Why do ants live so long?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/why-do-ants-live-so-long/2795#2795)
- [What reasons allow for women to outlive men?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/what-reasons-allow-for-women-to-outlive-men/3716#3716)